# CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in Ionic

Tags: node.js, angular, express, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a simple ionic (with angular) application that can connect to Nodejs backend but when I want to get the data from MongoDB I got this error I don't know how to solve it please help me I'm stack on this problem

[image]

Comment: are you added cors  in your express app..!!!  like  ..

var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors('*'))

Comment: no I don't add the cores in express app

Comment: after I add the cors in the express now the problem is solved thank you that mean a lot to me :D